# What exactly is meant by the quality of a qubit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer, superposition

When looking at a quantum annealer, we can see that D-Wave solutions have produced an annealer with over 5000 qubits whilst other companies that take a quantum gate approach have only managed 127 (IBM) and 256 QuEra.

When reading the literature they normally talk about how important it is to scale qubits and how a more powerful computer would have the capacity to scale to a larger number. However, they also mention that using quantum gates provides more flexibility in the range of problems that it can solve whilst a quantum annealer can only be utilised in solving optimisation problems. Therefore a lot of the literature makes the point that the quantity of qubits is not the only factor in determining the power of a super computer as the **quality** of the qubit is also of great importance.

My question is what are the factors that determine the quality of a qubit where higher quality qubits would result in a more powerful quantum computer.